# How does elastic search keep the index

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm wondering how does elasticsearch search so fast. Does it use inverted index and how is it represented in memory? How is it stored on disk? How does it load from disk to memory? And how does it merges indexes so fast (I mean when searching how does it combine two lists so fast)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

elasticsearch uses lucene to store inverse document indexes. Lucene in turn will store read-only files called segments with inverse index data. Each segment contains some documents. Those segments are read only and are never changed. To delete or update documents elasticsearch will maintain a delete/update list which will be used to overwrite results from read-only segments.

With this approach some segments might become obsolete altogether or contain only few up-to date data. Such segments will be rewritten or deleted.

There is an interesting elasticsearch plugin which visualizes the segments and the rewriting process:
https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-segmentspy

To see it in action start indexing a lot of data and see the segment information.

With the Segment API you can retrieve information about the segments:
http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-segments.html

Answer (score 1):

I'll share what I know of ElasticSearch (ES). Yes ES uses an inverted index, here is how it would be structured - if we have a white space analyzer on these documents -

```
{
    "_id": 1,
    "text": "Hello, John"
}
```

**AND**

```
{
    "_id": 2,
    "text": "Bonjour, John"
}
```

**INVERTED INDEX**

```
  Word   |   Docs 
___________________
 Hello   |    1
 Bonjour |    2
 John    |   1&2
```

This index is built at index time, the document is allocated to a shard based on hashing the document `ID`. Whenever a search request is made, a lookup is performed an all shards, the results of which are then merged and returned to the requester. The results are returned and merged blazingly fast due to the performance of the inverted index.

ES stores data within the data folder created once you have launched ES and created an index. The file structure resembles this - `/data/clustername/nodes/...`, if you look into this directory you will understand how it's organised. You can define how ES' index data is stored [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-store.html). For instance, all indexed data stored in memory on on disk.

There is plenty of information on the ES website there are also several published books on ES, you can see these [here](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=elasticsearch%20books&oq=elasticsearch%20books&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i64.3255j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: I've played with inverted index a little. In it I kept page's id and positions of a word in it: "word" : {page_id:0,2,12;next_page_id:10,15}. I serialized it as json string and kept it in db. After crawling half a million pages index for some common words reached about 5Mb, so taking it from db and deserializing it back alone took ages. And then working on such chunks of data trying to find common pages in it is also not fast. So I guess elastic search does things differently...

Comment: I wonder how it would deal with deleted doc. since finding deleted docs in inverted index would be costly.